# How to prettify dynamic code snippets in React?

Tags: reactjs, google-code-prettify, js-beautify, react-ace

I've looked into code prettifiers like google-code-prettify, beautify, etc. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get any of these to work in my React app. I am currently using react-ace to display dynamically populated code snippets, but they are only color-highlighted, not formatted.

Are there any simple examples of some way that I can get this to work in a React App? It doesn't have to be using Ace editor - that was sort of my hack to get the code displayed somewhat nicely.

Comment: You can use `prettier` to prettify your code. here is the link: https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html

Comment: @YashJoshi oh - I can use Prettier in the browser? I had no idea. And I can import it into my React component, yes? The trouble I had with other prettifiers is that they only supported node or vanilla JS.

Comment: yes, the link that I sent is the guide to use prettier in the browser. Yeah you can import and use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for this question, you can use prettier to format the code. You may need to configure different parser based on the language or framework you are using.

Here is a sample codesandbox for formatting JS code. Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-architecture-tm785?file=/src/App.js

Code for the main file:

```
import React from "react";
import prettier from "prettier/standalone";
import babylon from "prettier/parser-babel";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [code, setCode] = React.useState(`
        const a = "abc";


                const b = 'a'


           console.log(a);       
  `);

  const formatCode = () => {
    const formattedCode = prettier.format(code, {
      parser: "babel",
      plugins: [babylon]
    });

    setCode(formattedCode);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <textarea
        style={{ height: "100px", width: "100%", display: "block" }}
        value={code}
      />
      <button onClick={formatCode}>Format Code with Prettier</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to give this a try today and I'll let you know what happens :)

Comment: It turns out that to use prettier in browser JS, we have to import 'prettier/standalone' instead of 'prettier'. Thank you very much.