# How to auto-indent code string in PrismJS? NextJs APP

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, prismjs

i am trying to use PrimsJs in a react project, my objetive is create a static template page, and add snippets, i am not sure if is the best option(primsjs) but i am trying to auto-indent the code, because actually my code is rendered  in one line

---

[image]

THIS IS MY PAGE

```
import { MainLayout } from "../components/layouts/MainLayout";
import { Hero1, Hero1Code} from "../theme/blocks/hero/Hero1";

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <MainLayout>
            <h1>Home Page</h1>
            <Hero1 />
            <Hero1Code />
        </MainLayout>
    );
}
```

THIS IS MY PRIMSJS COMPONENT

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import Prism from "prismjs";
import "prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css";


export default function Code({ code, language }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="Code">
      <pre>
        <code className={`language-${language}`}>{code}</code>
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

THIS IS MY COMPONENT

```
import React from "react";

import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import Code from "../../../components/prism/code";

export const Hero1 = () => {
    return (
        <section className="wrapper bg-light">
           ...
        </section>

    );
};

export const Hero1Code = () => {
    const content = renderToString(<Hero1/>);
    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                <Code code={content} language="html" />
            </div>
        </>
    );
};
```

Any help will be very welcome, also i am open to try other package

Comment: Maybe [prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/browser.html)? [See previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61093115/how-to-prettify-dynamic-code-snippets-in-react).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that PrismJS has such an option, in my opinion it would be best to just indent the `code` string before passing it to the `<Code />` component.

You could use this library: https://github.com/zebzhao/indent.js

Import it:

```
import indent from 'indent.js';
```

And indent the code like this:

```
const content = indent.html(renderToString(<Hero1/>));
```

However, looking at your screenshot code example, I can see that you have a lot of `div`s smashed into one line. In this case, indentation would not really help, as it takes care of the relations between separate lines.

You could take a look at using a library like this, which seems to split code into separate lines.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty

Comment: Thanks i am gonna try, i let you know if works

Comment: looks like works, thanks